Error when returning children in nextjs server component
"use client";

-- Some imports and interfaces

const SubscriptionDataFetcher: React.FC<SubscriptionDataFetcherProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<SubscriptionData>({});

    -- Some functions
    return <>{children(data)}</>;
};

export default SubscriptionDataFetcher;

i have this app that needs to call a trpc route, and i have decided to call it like that and return the children to a server component:
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

--some interfaces

const Packages: React.FC = () => {
    <SubscriptionDataFetcher>
        {({ x, y }) => (

        )}
    </SubscriptionDataFetcher>
export default Packages;

I always get this error and have no idea what it means or how to handle correctly the children return:
Error: Functions are not valid as a child of Client Components. This may happen if you return children instead of <children /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
  <... children={function children}>


In your SubscriptionDataFetcher component, you're expecting children to be a function that takes data as an argument. However, in your Packages component, you're trying to use this function as a child of SubscriptionDataFetcher, which is causing the error.
To fix this, you can change SubscriptionDataFetcher to render its children directly, and pass data as a prop to the children. Here's how you can do it:
const SubscriptionDataFetcher: React.FC<SubscriptionDataFetcherProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<SubscriptionData>({});

  // Some functions

  return <>{children}</>;
};

Then, in your Packages component, you can use data as a prop:
const Packages: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <SubscriptionDataFetcher>
      <ChildComponent data={data} />
    </SubscriptionDataFetcher>
  );
};

If you want to keep the function-as-child pattern, you can use the React.cloneElement function to clone the child element and pass data as a prop:
const SubscriptionDataFetcher: React.FC<SubscriptionDataFetcherProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<SubscriptionData>({});

  // Some functions

  return <>{React.cloneElement(children, { data })}</>;
};

Then, in your Packages component, you can use data as a prop:
const Packages: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <SubscriptionDataFetcher>
      <ChildComponent />
    </SubscriptionDataFetcher>
  );
};

